# How to use twitter4j to get specify user's information within a specified period?

Tags: java, api, twitter, web-crawler, twitter4j

Now I use the twitter4j to crawl users data.
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

```
     List<Status> tweets=  twitter.getUserTimeline("xxxxx");
```

It return 20 tweets from those code. Would you please tell me that I can do If I want to get all the tweets from specify user in specified period?(e.g. one year？)

Thanks for your reading and sorry for my terrible expression

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `search` API. With search `Query` you can specify the `setSince()` method to retrieve tweets since that date. Please see documentation for `Query` [here](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Query.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I do not know how to get the tweets from specified user? We can not set the time by using twitter.getUserTimeline() right?

Comment: I think we can't specify date/time in timeline API